# Reading XML file with namespaces

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I need som help reading a XML that has namespaces.
I can read file with out any namepaces but not with namespaces..

XML sample:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OrderResponse xmlns:cac="urn:basic:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/" xmlns:cbc="urn:basic:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:BasicComponents-2" xmlns="urn:basic:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:OrderResponse-2">
  <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
  <cbc:AccountingCostCode>TESTER TEST</cbc:AccountingCostCode>
  <cac:OrderReference>
    <cbc:ID>100067010</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:IssueDate>2016-06-15</cbc:IssueDate>
    <cbc:OrderTypeCode>EDI</cbc:OrderTypeCode>
  </cac:OrderReference>
</OrderResponse>
```

I need to get the value of the ..
Im trying do it with DomDocument.
Here is my code:

```
function SearchXMLID($xml){
var_dump($xml);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($xml);
$id = $doc->getElementsByTagNameNS('urn:basic:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2','cbc:ID');

  foreach($id as $i){
    echo "<pre>";var_dump('NS',$i->nodeValue,PHP_EOL);"</pre>";

  }
}

$files = glob('dataXMl/*xml');
echo "<pre>";var_dump($files,PHP_EOL);"</pre>";

foreach($files as $f){
    SearchXMLID($f);
 }
```

This code works but is getting all namespaces with 'cbc:' and stores the in a string..

```html
    array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "dataXMl/test1.xml"
}
string(1) "
"
string(17) "dataXMl/test1.xml"
string(2) "NS"
string(40) "
    100000050
    2016-06-15
    EDI
  "
string(1) "
"
```

It gets all tags with the namespace 'cbc'.. but i want to get the tag 'cbc:ID' only.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert with php coding but my gut tells me that both of your parameters for getElementsByTagNameNS are wrong.

Try this:

```
$id = $doc->getElementsByTagNameNS('urn:basic:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:BasicComponents-2','ID');
```

i.e.

use the correct namespace-uri: "urn:basic:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:BasicComponents-2"

and drop the cbc prefix

Comment: I tried that as well, to just enter 'ID' but it dosent output anything

Comment: php docs say local-name.  Local name does not use a prefix.   http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagnamens.php